# SQL : Remove duplicate based on a critera

Tags: sql, sql-server, duplicates, sql-server-2016

I'm mostly new to SQL, thus I don't know a lot about all the advanced option it provides. I work currently with MS SQL Server 2016 (Developer edition).

I have the following result:

```
|  Type  |  Role  |                 GUID                 |
|--------|--------|--------------------------------------|
|   B    |   0    |                 ABC                  |
|   B    |   0    |                 KLM                  |
|   A    |   0    |                 CDE                  |
|   A    |   0    |                 EFG                  |
|   A    |   1    |                 CDE                  |
|   B    |   1    |                 ABC                  |
|   B    |   1    |                 GHI                  |
|   B    |   1    |                 IJK                  |
|   B    |   1    |                 KLM                  |
```

From the following SELECT :

```
SELECT DISTINCT
        Type,
        Role,
        GUID
```

I'm looking to count the GUID following these constrains :

-> If there is multiple row with the same GUID, only count the row with "Role" set to "1", else, count the one with a "Role" set to 0
-> if there is only one, count it either as a "Role 0" or "Role 1", according to their own Role value.

My objective is to get the following result :

```
|  Type  |  Role  |              COUNT(GUID)             |
|--------|--------|--------------------------------------|
|   A    |   0    |                  1                   | => counted EFG as there was no other row with a "Role" set to 1
|   A    |   1    |                  1                   | => counted CDE with "Role" set to 1, but the row with "Role" set to 0 is ignored
|   B    |   1    |                  4                   |
```

Comment: 1. What version of sql server are you working with? 2. What have you tried so far? 3. If there are multiple rows with the same "guid", but none of them with role set to 1, what should you do?

Comment: 1. I'm using SQL server 2016  
2. I tried to use to use "DISTINCT"  
3. I already use "DISTINCT" on the first request ("SELECT DISTINCT Type, Role, GUID"), thus this case shouldn't occur.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `NOT EXISTS` could be used for this.

For example:

```
declare @T table ([Type] char(1), [Role] int, [GUID] varchar(3));

insert into @T ([Type], [Role], [GUID]) values
('A',0,'CDE'),
('A',0,'EFG'),
('A',1,'CDE'),
('B',0,'ABC'),
('B',0,'KLM'),
('B',1,'ABC'),
('B',1,'GHI'),
('B',1,'IJK'),
('B',1,'KLM');

select [Type], [Role], COUNT(DISTINCT [GUID]) as TotalUniqueGuid
from @T t
where not exists (
  select 1 
  from @T t1
  where t.[Type] = t1.[Type]
    and t.[Role] = 0 and t1.[Role] > 0
    and t.[GUID] = t1.[GUID]
)
group by [Type], [Role];
```

**Returns:**

```
Type Role TotalUniqueGuid
A    0    1
A    1    1
B    1    4
```

Answer (score 3):

Your query is not implementing the logic you mention.  Here is a method that uses subqueries and window functions:

```
select type, role, count(*)
from (select t.*,
             count(*) over (partition by GUID) as guid_cnt
      from t
     ) t
where (guid_cnt > 1 and role = 1) or
      (guid_cnt = 1 and role = 0)
group by type, role;
```

The subquery gets the count of rows that match a `GUID`.  The outer `where` then uses that for filtering according to your conditions.

Note:  `role` is not a good choice for a column name.  It is a keyword (see [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-role-transact-sql)) and may be reserved in the future (see [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/reserved-keywords-transact-sql)).

Comment: This seems to only give me 2 occurrence for "Type B, Role 1", where there should be 4 occurrences.

As for the name of the column, they are anonymized names, I use a prefix (something like "1234_"), thus, no conflict risk.

Comment: @Dremor . . . According to your rules, it should have "ABC" and "KLM" because they appear twice.  "GHI" and "IJK" appear only once, so role "1" is not counted.  If you have a different set of rules, *don't* change the question; ask another one.  Changing the question will invalidate the answers of people who have tried to help you.  And that can draw downvotes.

Comment: Indeed, my rule was wrong, I wanted to count the row even if there was only a row with "Role = 1". In another hand, I provided the expected result on my question, if you saw that it was incoherent with the rule, you could have at least asked for precision. 
On the edit side, nothing prevent those who answer to edit their question, provided of course that the one who asked the question take the time to notify them with a comment (like this one).